# Append partial view passing in parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, actionresult

I am new to MVC coming from web forms and I am struggling getting my head around how you pass parameters into a partial view.

I have the following action result.  I want to be able to append a new copy of a partial view to my page when a user clicks a button passing in na new Id.  The idea is you get a small section of data but the user can request more which just gets tagged on the end with a different ID value.

Currently this works only when using the routing with an id at the end, but is then static and I cannot add any more.

```
    public ActionResult GetAllDaysByDate(int Id)
    {
        DateTime theTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Id.ToString(),
                                               "yyyyMMdd",
                                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                               DateTimeStyles.None);

        YourDayEntities context = new YourDayEntities();
        var days = context.GetAllDaysByDate(theTime);

        List<Day> day = new List<Day>();

        foreach (var item in days)
        {
            Day d = new Day { DayId = item.DayId, DayDesc = item.DayDesc, DayDate = item.DayDate, ImgUrl = item.ImgUrl };
            day.Add(d);
        }

        return View(day);
    }
```

I have tried various different methods to pass a param in, such as the following.

```
@Html.Partial("_GetAllDaysByDatePartial", new ViewDataDictionary(new { Id = 20160101 })) );
```

But this is throwing an error.  Am I going about this all wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to call an action method and returns the partial it generates, then you need `@Html.Action("_GetAllDaysByDatePartial", new { ID = 20160101 })`, not `@Html.Partial()`

Comment: How about to append that partial, would you use the same?

Comment: Append to what? Its not really clear what your wanting to do. If you want to dynamically update a page without regenerating a view, then you need to use ajax. And it appears you want a `DateTime` - so use `DateTime`, not `int`

Comment: Thats correct, I want have have a blank page, then using a text box for example add a date, I then want to click a button which adds my partial view using that date as the param to the page.  I then want the user to be able to change the date, press the button again and then another partial view gets added to the page but the first one stays there too.

Comment: The you need javascript/jquery to handle the click event of your button and use ajax to pass the value of the textbox to your method and update the DOM with the partial view it returns

Comment: Thanks - Its the bit about updating the DOM I don't undertstand, I will try and google this thank you!